# Correct use of Angular 6 ReplaySubject for caching - observers length keeps growing

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement data caching in my Angular 6 app using `ReplaySubject` and am not sure if the growing size of the `ReplaySubject` observers is an issue.

In my data.service I am checking to see if there are any existing observers. If so, I return a reference to the `ReplaySubject` to get the 'cached' value. If not, I make a network request to get the data and add the data to the `ReplaySubject`.

```
// data.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private dataObs$ = new ReplaySubject<any>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getData(forceRefresh?: boolean): any {
    // return last value (i.e. cache) from ReplaySubject or add data to it
    if (!this.dataObs$.observers.length || forceRefresh) {
      console.log('network request')
      this.dataObs$.next(this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'));
    }
    
    console.log('# of Observers ' + this.dataObs$.observers.length);
  
    return this.dataObs$;
  }
}
```

Then in my components, I subscribe to this data.service and get the value from the `ReplaySubject`.

```
// pricing.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'pricing',
  template: '<h4>Pricing</h4>'
})
export class PricingComponent implements OnInit  {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => console.log( 'pricing data'));
  } 
}
```

This looks to work, but when you navigate back and forth between components that use this data.service, the `ReplaySubject` observers.length keeps growing. This can be seen in the console of this StackBlitz example and navigating between the Pricing and Mgmt routes - https://stackblitz.com/edit/replay-subject-observers-length

Perhaps there is a better way to handle caching to limit redundant network requests but if this is in fact a good use of `ReplaySubject`, then I'm wondering if this growing `observers.length` is a concern, and if so what should be done to limit the number of observers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to unsubscribe when your component is destroyed. You can either do that by using the return value of the subscribe method or you can use the takeUntil operator. Here is an example how you could do that with takeUntil:

```
export class PricingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {

  // We can use a subject to emit a signal when the component is destroyed
  private destroyed$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getData()
        // Take values from the service until the component is destroyed
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
        .subscribe(data => console.log( 'pricing data'));
  } 

  // Here we emit when the component is destroyed
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next();
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
}
```

**Edit:** There is still another thing we need to change regarding how you handle your data service. Consumers should take care of their own subscriptions. Your service should only care if the data has already been requested and if a refresh is forced.

I updated your service and added some comments in the code to explain a bit more..

```
@Injectable()
    export class DataService {

    private dataObs$ = new ReplaySubject<any>();
    // Introduce new value to keep track on if data has been requested
    private hasBeenRequested = false;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getData(forceRefresh?: boolean): any {
        // Only take into account if data has been requested or a refresh is forced.
        if (!this.hasBeenRequested || forceRefresh) {
            // Remember that we have issued a request for the data
            this.hasBeenRequested = true;
            console.log('network request')
            this.dataObs$.next(this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'));
        }

        // At this points you will always get 0 subscribers, because here we only return
        // the subject. The subscription happens after the return.
        console.log('# of Observers ' + this.dataObs$.observers.length);

        // To demonstrate that I added a delay which logs the subscriber count after the return    
        setTimeout(() => console.log('# of Observers after timeout', this.dataObs$.observers.length), 10)
        return this.dataObs$;
    }

}
```

I also added an updated stack blitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/replay-subject-observers-length-ouvcbu?

**Edit2:**
You have asked why your code is requesting with each page change, when you switch `!hasBeenRequested` into `observers.length === 0` in the if statement of the data service. Maybe to understand a bit better what is happening  you need to think about what happens with the service and your components.

1. `ngOnInit` is called on the first component. At the point of the request there are 0 observers, so the service issues an http request. After subscribing the observer count is 1.
2. Navigate to the second component.
3. Now first of all `ngOnDestroy` is called on the first component, which leads to the component unsubscribing and setting the observer count back to 0.
4. Only now `ngOnit` of the second component is called. The observer count is now again 0, so the call to the backend is issued again.

This means that `observers.length` is always 0 when we are in the process of subscribing. The old page always unsubscribes before the new one subscribes.

Comment: Thanks, but doing this causes two issues which you can see by clicking between pages: 1) a network request is reissued when moving between pages (reason for the ReplaySubject) and 2) the data sent to the subscriber gets duplicated. I've added your code to StackBlitz and you can uncomment the .pipe lines to see this.

Comment: I see. I updated my answer. With the changes in the data service you should not have those problems anymore.

Comment: Thanks. This looks to be the result I wanted. One question I have is, if I change this line:  if (!this.hasBeenRequested || forceRefresh) to this: if (this.dataObs$.observers.length < 1 || forceRefresh) - and then switch between pages, the data sent to subscribe gets duplicated. I don't understand why this occurs as I thought that data.service is a singleton and will return the same reference to the this.dataObs$ by each subscriber and would have the same result as your !this.hasBeenRequested flag. Do you know why the data gets duplicated when this.dataObs$.observers.length < 1 is used?

Comment: I added another edit to my answer, it was a bit to big to put it in the comments. I hope this makes it a bit clearer.